# Append text to the title

Tags: macros

In a class file I want to append an email address to the title. My naive approach was:

```
\AtBeginDocument{
  \title{\@title – [email]}
  \maketitle
}
```

But this just doesn't work. If I do `\@latex@error{\@title}` afterwars for debugging purposes, I still get the old title. What am I doing wrong here and how would be a correct approach? (Also, `\def\@title{…}` didn't work and `\def\oldtitle\@title \title{\oldtitle …}` did neither)

Comment: What is you class file?